# Settime out messing with onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to create a automatic image slider which also responds to an onclick function, for some odd reason the onclick event is pretty much doing nothinig i suspect its cause of the settime out as javascript is single threaded but im no master at javascript! could someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong stuck with this for the past two days! thank you!

```js
var i = 0;      
var starterimages= [];
var time = 3000;  
var eventaction=0;
var timeoutId;



starterimages[0] = "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f4/92/39/f492399e154bd9f564d7fc5299c19911--purple-rain-deep-purple.jpg";
starterimages[1] = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/purple-butterfly-isolated-on-white-260nw-44004850.jpg";
starterimages[2] = "https://www.birdscanada.org/images/inbu_norm_q_townsend.jpg";




var nextbutton=document.querySelector("#rightbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click",rightbuttonclick);

var prevbutton=document.querySelector("#leftbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click",leftbuttonclick);

function rightbuttonclick()
{
eventaction=1;
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

function leftbuttonclick()
{
eventaction=2;
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

function changeImg(){
  
  document.getElementById('startersliders').src = starterimages[i];

  if(eventaction==1)
  {
    i++;
    if(i < starterimages.length - 1) 
    {document.getElementById('startersliders').src = starterimages[i];
    eventaction=0;}
    else
    {
      i=0;
      document.getElementById('startersliders').src = starterimages[i];
    eventaction=0;
    }
    
  }
  else if(eventaction==2)
  {
    i--;
     if(i== - 1) 
     {
       i=3;
        document.getElementById('startersliders').src = starterimages[i];
     eventaction=0;
     }
     else
    {
      document.getElementById('startersliders').src = starterimages[i];
    eventaction=0;
    }
  }
  else if(eventaction==0){
  if(i < starterimages.length - 1){
    
    i++; 
  } 
  else { 
  
    i = 0;
  }
  }

  // Run function every x seconds
timeoutId = setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}


// Run function when page loads
window.onload=changeImg;
```

```css
#staratersliders {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button3" id="leftbutton"> previous</button>
<img id="startersliders" />

<button class="button button3" id="rightbutton">next</button>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for posting on SO! For starters, you're improperly using [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout). `clearTimeout` takes an ID value that is _returned_ by the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) call. So, you need to do something like `var timeoutId; ... timeoutId = setTimeout("changeImg()", time); ... clearTimeout(timeoutId)`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst i edited the code as you said still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it all working in Firefox 51, buttons included. Just paste the whole thing in a blank page and save it with an `.htm` or `.html` extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE=HTML><html><meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>

var i = 0;      
var starterimages= [];
var time = 3000;  
var eventaction=0;
var timeoutId;

starterimages[0] = "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f4/92/39/f492399e154bd9f564d7fc5299c19911--purple-rain-deep-purple.jpg";
starterimages[1] = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/purple-butterfly-isolated-on-white-260nw-44004850.jpg";
starterimages[2] = "https://www.birdscanada.org/images/inbu_norm_q_townsend.jpg";

function rightbuttonclick() {
  eventaction = 1;
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  changeImg();
}

function leftbuttonclick() {
  eventaction = 2;
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  changeImg();
}

function changeImg() {
  if (eventaction == 1) {
    if (i < starterimages.length - 1) {
      i++;
      document.getElementById('startersliders').src=starterimages[i];  
      eventaction = 0;
    } else { 
      i = 0;
      document.getElementById('startersliders').src=starterimages[i];
      eventaction = 0;
    }
  } else if (eventaction == 2) {
    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
      i = 2;
      document.getElementById('startersliders').src=starterimages[i]; 
      eventaction = 0;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('startersliders').src=starterimages[i];
      eventaction = 0;
    }
  } else {
    if (i < starterimages.length - 1) {
      i++;
    } else {
      i = 0;
    };

    document.getElementById('startersliders').src=starterimages[i];
    eventaction = 0;
  } 

  timeoutId=setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}
</script>

<style>
#startersliders {width: 10%;height: 10%;position: relative;margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;}
</style>

<body onload="changeImg();">

<button class="button button3" id="leftbutton">previous</button>
<img id="startersliders">
<button class="button button3" id="rightbutton">next</button>

<script>
var nextbutton=document.querySelector("#rightbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click",rightbuttonclick);

var prevbutton=document.querySelector("#leftbutton");
prevbutton.addEventListener("click",leftbuttonclick);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that there is a bug in this code - and extra `;`. I pointed it out in the code which I have now formatted.

Comment: That's an 'unnecessary' semi-colon.  It will flag as such in a js tester but it's not a 'bug' that will break the code.  I just use it so I can spot the end of a large multi-level if statement more easily.

Comment: It also helps avoid cut and paste errors if a line break is removed and the following statement ends up on the same line by mistake.  This seems to be a pretty good reference.https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/507f6dd09266b70200000d7e

Comment: Good callout and sorry about that - I wasn't paying enough attention to where it was.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because this:

```
setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
```

Is invalid syntax for `setTimeout`. To fix it, just do this:

```
setTimeout(changeImg, time);
```

Comment: It does *really look* invalid, but unfortunately, it's not, `setTimeout` also accepts essentially `eval` strings as well

Answer (score 0):

```
var nextbutton=document.querySelector("#rightbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click",rightbuttonclick);

var prevbutton=document.querySelector("#leftbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click",leftbuttonclick);
```

I copy/pasted the code into my machine and the above came up null because they need to be between script tags at the bottom of the body of the doc.
When the parser sees those at the top, it doesn't know what #rightbutton and #leftbutton are because it hasn't parsed the html in the body section yet so it comes back as a null element

just move them to the bottom of the body section after the html and put script /script tags around them and see what happens

You need to do both of the above, what Matthew Herbst said is correct and what  Jack Bashford said is correct.  Create a variable for the setTimeout

```
var mytimeinverval;
var mytimer;
mytimer=setTimeout(myfunctionname,mytimeinterval);
```

The function name inside the setTimeout doesn't get quotes or parenthesis.
If you put parenthesis in, it might fire instantly or who knows?
It still recognizes myfunctionname as a function without the parenthesis.
Putting quotes around it makes it a string-won't work in my experience.
I don't want credit, they answered it, just letting you know to do both.

Comment: @i edited the code as mathew suggested still not working and settime out function accepts methods with paranthesis given or without paranthesis or with just function name that doesnot make any difference but still gave a try and results the same

Comment: I tested 4 permutations:

Comment: I tested 4 permutations:with quotes and parens-correct, quotes without parens-no fire,parens no quotes-fires instantly,no parens no quotes-correct so sorry, you're way with both works just like my way with neither.  I'll look at it again but if you  did the var mytimer=setTimeout as well then I'm stuck.